# Selenium. How to delete current PHP WebDriver and install older version?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, centos7

I used this code to install Facebook Web Driver on Centos 7:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar require facebook/webdriver
```

But now I need to uninstall it and install version 1.0.2 of Facebook Web Driver. Please let know how to accomplish these both things.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have manually replaced lib directory by the files of older version